# Convergence or divergence of $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(2n+1)^{2}} {3^{n}(2n)!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Show if the series converges or diverges.
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}  \frac{(2n+1)^{2}} {3^{n}(2n)!}$$

Can someone please help with proving this? (I think it converges)

Comment: What about trying **yourself** some test? Say, the ratio (D'Alembert's) test or something else...?

Comment: Factorials?  The ratio test is a quick go-to.

Comment: Hint: The denominator tends to $+\infty$ way faster than the numerator. You can easily do that by comparison if you wish, as an alternative to the ratio test.

Comment: @julien is correct; $3^n$ alone asymptotically dominates $(2n+1)^2$ (in general, $x^n\in\mathcal{o}(e^x)$).

Answer (score 5):

$$\dfrac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n)!} = \dfrac{4n^2+4n+1}{(2n)!} = \dfrac{(2n)(2n-1)+6n+1}{(2n)!} = \dfrac1{(2n-2)!}+ 3 \cdot \dfrac1{(2n-1)!} + \dfrac1{(2n)!}$$
Now $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n)!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{(2n)!} + 3 \cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{(2n-1)!} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{(2n-2)!}$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{(2n)!} & = \dfrac{\exp(\sqrt{x})+\exp(-\sqrt{x})}2\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{(2n-1)!} & = \sqrt{x} \cdot \dfrac{\exp(\sqrt{x})-\exp(-\sqrt{x})}2\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{(2n-2)!} & = x \cdot \dfrac{\exp(\sqrt{x})+\exp(-\sqrt{x})}2
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n)!} x^n = \dfrac{(x+\sqrt{x}+1) \exp(\sqrt{x})+(x-\sqrt{x}+1) \exp(-\sqrt{x})}2$$

Comment: Wow that's brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the ration test (as suggested by @DonAntonio in the comment above)
$$
\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert = \frac{(2n+3)^23^n(2n)!}{3^{n+1}(2n + 2)!(2n+1)^2}
$$
Find the limit of this as $n\to \infty$. If the factorials are bothering your then think:
$$
\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!} = \frac{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n) }{2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n)\cdot (2n+1)\cdot (2n+2)}.
$$

Comment: You confuse $2n! $ with $(2n)!$.

Comment: $(2n)!\neq2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdot\dots\cdot2n$

Comment: @oldrinb: Thanks! I fixed it.

Comment: No problem! I'm not too sure why the other guy bothered to find a closed form expression for the series